# c++ reference type as recursive function parameter

Tags: c++

```
Node * BST::insert_real(int key, Node *& node)
{
    if (node == nullptr)
        return node = new Node(key);

    if (key < node->key)
        return insert_real(key, node->left);
    else if (key > node->key)
        return insert_real(key, node->right);
    else
        return nullptr;
}

Node * BST::insert(int key)
{
    return insert_real(key, header->left);
}
```

BinarySearchTree, the insert function.

If the `key` always goes `left`, when the function `insert_all()` runs to the position `node = new Node(key)` , whether the `node` is equivalent to `header->left->left->left->left->left->......->left->left`?

if my guess above is right, the code `header->left->left->left->left->left->......->left->left` will bring some burden.(if so, i will replace `Node*&` with `Node**`)

---

The words I say above is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the key always goes left, when the function insert_all() runs to the position node = new Node(key) , whether the node is equivalent to header->left->left->left->left->left->......->left->left

No, in the below call you are not changing `node` parameter which you received.You are just calling `insert_real()` with some other parameter.

```
return insert_real(key, node->left);
```

The only time you change `node` is below

```
if (node == nullptr)
    return node = new Node(key);
```